# How to add Click Listener In Auto Slider Image

Tags: kotlin

How to add click listener for the auto slider image in kotlin i have searched on everywhere but not getting valid ans everywhere it is showing in java only

I had tried with java but not getting proper solution using the youtube video.

Need help to solve the issues